# couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-promise"

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've done the followings to use eslint globally so not repeat on every new project but I am not able to get the eslint plugin part to work. what step am I missing:

- installed eslint (& the eslint-plugin-promise ) globally
- created a .eslintrc file in my home directory ,and included these in it

```
    {
     "env": {
     "browser": true,
     "es6": true,
     "node": true
     },
      "plugins": [
        "promise"
      ]
    }
```

and I expect that when I run eslint in any directory the plugin to be known.
so in my work directory I add a .eslintrc.json with all the rules I wanted to apply
but I get these errors:

```
   1:1  error  Definition for rule 'promise/always-return' was not found    promise/always-return
   1:1  error  Definition for rule 'promise/catch-or-return' was not found  promise/catch-or-return
   1:1  error  Definition for rule 'promise/no-nesting' was not found       promise/no-nesting
```

Now if I add this to local  .eslintrc

```
  "plugins": [
    "promise",
  ],
```

I get this error : ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-promise".
and recommends me to install it locally. but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade to the latest version of `ESLint` and make sure it's configured properly in `.eslintrc.json`

Comment: eslint v7.16.0 . both config files are .eslintrc.json